# Capistrano ignore a file in /bin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

After setup Delayed_job in development, here is the file `delayed_job` in /bin directory. When I deploy project to server, the file `delayed_job` just disappears.

Comment: Does your .gitignore file have a rule to ignore the `bin` folder? I.e. is the file not under revision control?

Comment: Yes, I've checked this possibilities. Now, I found that the /bin folder is a link to shared/bin folder on server. Does this do something I don't know for in situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've found that the `bin` folder is sym-linked to a `shared/bin` folder (on deploy?) you'd need to scp your delayed_job executable into the `shared/bin` folder on server at this point. Or you may be able to do this on deploy just before the point in the cap deploy files where the symbolic link is made. Or perhaps just do it once now (and again in the future as needed) and then add the bin folder to your .gitignore. In fact I'd recommend this latter approach in case you start using spring with binstubs in development (as you wouldn't want these special executables being copied up to your server for production mode).

Comment: Yeah, I should add it to .gitignore.